# Centering cell content in multirow

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

According to the table code below, Could anyone please help me to:

1. center vertically and horizontally `TextB1`, `TextAB`, `TextC0`, `TextC1`, `TextC2`, `TextC17` and `TextC18`
2. Draw vertical line along the right side of the cell containg `TextC0`. i.e. drawing a line along the left side of the cells containing `TextC1` ...until... `TextC6`. The `|` can't do this with the `\multirow` command.

I'll really be grateful if you help me on that.

```
    \begin{table}[h]
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}
    \def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm} >    {\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm} m{1.8cm} X >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|m{3.6cm}}{\centering{\textbf{Vertically and horizontally centered  Text (width = 2cm (colum1) + 2cm (column2) = 4cm)}}} & \centering{\textbf{Vertically and horizontally centered Text (width = 1.8cm)}} & \textbf{Justified and vertically centered Text (width= X)} & \textbf{Vertically and horizontally centered Text (width=2.5cm)}   \tabularnewline \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{TextA1} & TextA2 & LongText1 LongText1 LongText1 LongText1 LongText1 LongText1 & \multirow{5}{*}{TextAB}  \\ \cline{1-4}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{\multirow{4}{*}{TextB1}} & TextB2 & LongText2 LongText2 LongText2 LongText2 LongText2 LongText2 & \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & TextB3 & LongText3 LongText3 LongText3 LongText3 LongText3 LongText3 & \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & TextB4 & LongText4 LongText4 LongText4 LongText4 LongText4 LongText4 & \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & TextB5 & LongText5 LongText5 LongText5 LongText5 LongText5 LongText5 & \\ \hline
    \multirow{10}{*}{TextC0} & \multirow{2}{*}{TextC1} & TextC7 & LongText6 LongText6 LongText6 LongText6 LongText6 LongText6 & \multirow{2}{*}{TextC17} \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & TextC8 &  LongText7 LongText7 LongText7 LongText7 LongText7 LongText7 & \\ \cline{2-5}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{TextC2} & TextC9 & LongText8 LongText8 LongText8 LongText8 LongText8 LongText8 & \multirow{4}{*}{TextC18} \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & TextC10 & LongText9 LongText9 LongText9 LongText9 LongText9 LongText9 & \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & TextC11 & LongText10 LongText10 LongText10 LongText10 LongText10 LongText10 & \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & TextC12 & LongText11 LongText11 LongText11 LongText11 LongText11 LongText11 & \\  \cline{2-5}
    & TextC3 & TextC13 & LongText11 LongText11 LongText11 LongText11 LongText11 LongText11 & TextC19 \\ \cline{2-5}
    & TextC4 & TextC14 & LongText12 LongText12 LongText12 LongText12 LongText12 LongText12 & TextC20 \\ \cline{2-5}
    & TextC5 & TextC15 & LongText13 LongText13 LongText13 LongText13 LongText13 LongText13 & TextC21 \\ \cline{2-5}
    & TextC6 & TextC16 & LongText14 LongText14 LongText14 LongText14 LongText14 LongText14 & TextC22 \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: No1 is all-right, they're centered, what is the problem with it?

Comment: I want them to be centered vertically and horizontally in the multirow

Comment: "More" centered than [this (screenshot)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71173308/tabularx.png)?! They are centered.

Comment: Oh you haven't changed anything ? The result in my compil is quite different. Could you please take a look on the result of my compil here : http://www.filedropper.com/tabularx ? Thanks

Comment: @user40953 please always provide a _complete_  (small) document showing the problem, not just a fragment, then communication is a lot easier.

Comment: I am sorry But I did'nt understand how to include images, pdf, url in this forum. I found complicated to provide a performed problem show.

Comment: @user40953 you don't need to include urls, just edit the question so your example starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and generates a table that shows the problem. Just a fragment starting `\begin{table}` makes it very hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)